# Get only photos from users wall feed using facebook graph api

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=token
```

will return all feeds for a user news feed. But i am looking for filters like type=post or type=photos etc

Is this functionality available in facebook api??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter results in [`home`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home) connection of [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) filtered by user's stream filters by using `filter` argument. For example photos may be accessed with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?filter=app_2305272732
```

And Links:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?filter=app_2309869772
```

`filter` should be one of those returned by next FQL query:

```
SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()
```

See [`stream_filter`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/) table for details.

**BTW:** Beware, not everything may be possible to use as filters, for example statuses (those easier to access via `/me/statuses` than via `/me/home`)...

Comment: @Scripter, would you mind me asking where you found those filter keys, app_2309869772, and app_2305272732? I tried searching their documentation but couldn't find any page listening all the available keys.

Comment: I dont think this works anymore, it gives me links,videos & photos for this https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/104266592953439/feed?fields=type,message&filter=app_2309869772

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it documented, but I just tried the following url and it worked:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home/photos?access_token=token
```

Comment: But thats a problem. photos are woking. Now if I need likes or shares. Its not working.. Basically i need to analyze user new feed based upon the type.

Comment: +1 for knowledge, but you better avoid usage of undocumented functionality provided by Facebook, even documented stuff *periodically* f#cked up...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this with `fql`, I recently wrote a [blog post](http://pulkitgoyal.in/2012/12/26/getting-all-photos-and-videos-from-facebook-news-feed/) of getting photos and videos from Facebook news feed. And here is the query that I use.

```
SELECT actor_id, created_time, likes, post_id, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN ( SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND (name = "Photos" OR name = "Video"))
```